# Notification сообщение через час после последнего посещения приложения

Tags: android, android-notification

Привет. Вопрос скорее теоретический чем практический, так как не могу смекнуть.

Задача в следующем. Приложение дает бонусы своему пользователю раз в час, нужно вывести в статус сообщение с уведомлением: мол, зайди и забери, в том случае, если юзер не в нем (он и так его получит), когда бонус получен я пишу в память время, запускаю сервис со сном на час и там вызываю `Notification.Builder`, постоянное напоминание не требуется, только раз.

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)+(60*60));
            sendNotif();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    void sendNotif() {

        //Notification

    }
}
```

Почему то сообщения не выводятся после релиза, или один/два раза и все...
Может я в корне не верно понял решение?

Comment: у меня похожая беда, только у меня сервис запускается по `AlarmManager` и после отработки должен отправлять сообщение - и вот его он отправляет абсолютно рандомно. Может у вас нашлось решение проблемы?